# Skipping slow websites when looping through an array of URLs using watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to loop through an array of websites in Chrome using watir-webdriver, but I always encounter an error on certain websites. Recently, I have had this problem with http://adage.com. The loop will execute perfectly until it reaches http://adage.com and then it will hang until the following error is displayed:

```
/Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
from /Users/default/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
from /Users/default/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in `response_for'
from /Users/default/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:38:in `request'
from /Users/default/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
from /Users/default/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
from /Users/default/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
from /Users/default/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:536:in `getActiveElement'
from /Users/default/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:60:in `active_element'
from /Users/default/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:136:in `send_keys'
from /Users/default/Dropbox/beta_scripts/loop_test.rb:16:in `rescue in <main>'
from /Users/default/Dropbox/beta_scripts/loop_test.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea how to avoid this. I have tried setting timeouts and even sending the `ESC` key during rescue to stop Chrome from loading the page, but have not had any success. Ultimately, I want to be able to *reliably* load an array of 500+ websites in succession, but this seems impossible given the likelihood that one of the websites will hang. **Is there any way to stop a slow page from loading and move on to the next element in the array?**

Below is a shortened version of my code that isolates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

sites = ["twitter.com", "cars.com", "autotrader.com", "rolex.com", "newyorker.com", "adage.com", "theatlantic.com", "pcmag.com"]

sites.each do |uri|
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(10) do
      b.goto uri
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error => e_time
    sleep 5
    b.send_keys :escape
    p "#{uri} is taking forever to load (#{e_time})"
  rescue Exception => e_exception
    p e_exception
  end
end

b.close
```

Comment: I don't understand python, but estimating the website load time like this would probably not be good idea. And i say this because some pages have complex pageload ajax requests which take time to finish even though main website has finished loading. Probably, using unstable version of firefox capability might help you.

Comment: it is not python; it is ruby..

Comment: increase your timeout and give a try.

Comment: I put the timeout at 10 seconds only for the sake of this example. In the "production" code, the timeout is at 3 minutes, but the site will hang indefinitely anyway. I just want to be able to skip any page that takes longer than `x` minutes to load, but that doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can understand your frustration mate because I have encountered the same when dealing with selenium webdriver. Here it is what you need to do to be 100% sure that your script will run flawless and robust till the end for your 500+ websites.

```
    sites.each do |uri|    
!30.times { if ((b.goto uri)rescue false)then break else sleep 1; end }     
    end
```

The code above will try to access each website for a maximum of 30sec and then move to the next website.

Comment: Your code seems to throw an error upon execution. I cleaned it up (made `Rescue` lowercase and moved the final `end` statement before `rescue`), but it still doesn't seem to work. While I don't get the error above when accessing adage.com, Chrome still hangs indefinitely and watir-webdriver does not move on to the next item in the array. Any ideas?

Comment: I take that back, I still got the above error. It just took much, much longer.

Comment: Well this code is working for selenium webdriver..I've tried to convert it to the equivalent for Watir..it should be something very close to that..let me try once more..